# Where to find the data of Facebook Instant Article in Google analytics console?

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-instant-articles

I am very keen to know that how to check the data coming from Facebook instant article? Does it come under the standard report of GA(web) or app? We have put the standard tracking code in FB instant article. Do I need to customize it like using campaign source and all or what? Please help me . I am not able to see the data coming in from instant article.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about google analytics and is not programing related may be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**comment:** Since the question tackles code implementation and there is an answer already here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310439/how-to-track-content-statistics-for-facebook-instant-articles-with-google-analyt) it might be alright to ask here.

**answer:** If tracked data can be analyzed using your web or app property depends (a) whether or not traffic gets redirected to a website or app, if the Facebook user does not use the Facebook App, but his mobile browser and (b) on your own implementation.

**A** is pretty straight forward. Redirect to a website --> use web tracking, redirect to an app --> use app tracking. If by standard tracking code you mean this snippet

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-81224138-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

then you use web tracking. [App tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/screens) uses screen views instead of pageviews including some code like this `ga('send','screenview)`

So, to answer **B** look out for the above code. You might also set campaign and source to easily identfiy the Instant Article Traffic, e.g. like this

```
  ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'Facebook');
  ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'Instant Article');
```

This should be placed before `ga('send.'pageview')`

Comment: You don't need to hardcode campaignSource and campaignMedium. Here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55262002/5331610