# Google Analytics UTM Parameter for Facebook Instant Article

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-instant-articles

I have an enquiry that I need your advice.

For example,I have boosted a post from Facebook and I have indicated the URL of the post with UTM parameters from the Campaign URL Builder as the below:
Source:Facebook
Medium:social

As the above post is also a Facebook instant article and I have specified the Google Analytics codes in my page with the following UTM parameters:
Source:Facebook
Medium:social IA

May I enquire which UTM parameter will Facebook send to Google Analytics when the post is viewed as an instant article?

Thank You.

Comment: Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hardcode `campaignSource` and `campaignMedium` in the tracking snippet. You can set `referrer` instead.
Here is the full snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55262002/5331610