# Google Analytics + FB Instant ARticles: What Source/Medium should be used to make IA traffic show in "Social" channel

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

This question is related to, but distinct from [How to track content Statistics for Facebook Instant Articles with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310439/how-to-track-content-statistics-for-facebook-instant-articles-with-google-analyt/36574530#36574530)

This question assumes we already have Google Analytics integrated into our Instant Articles setup, for which I recommend the following:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'YOUR_UID_REPLACE_THIS', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'Facebook');
  ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'Social Instant Article');
  ga('set', 'title', ia_document.title);
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

The active question is what the `campaignSource` and `campaignMedium` values should be in order to have IA traffic show up in the **Acquisition > Channels** view of GA, and specifically, to get it into the **Social** and **Facebook** channels.

The code above uses `Facebook` and `Social Instant Article`, which work to identify IA traffic using the **Acquisition > Source / Medium** report, but in the **Acquisition > Channels** report they show up under **Other** and not even in **Social** at all.

So what, if anything, can we set our  `campaignSource` and `campaignMedium` to to fix this?

Part of the answer is that we can [edit the default channel defintions, such that our custom source / medium always get filtered into **Social** (GA reference)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6010097), which you can read more about in this [MarketingLand article](https://marketingland.com/google-analytics-social-channel-broken-heres-fix-227330). This should let us at least get this traffic out of **Other** and into **Social**, but I'm still not sure if it will show up under **Social > Facebook** or something else.

My idea is that maybe using source: `facebook` or source `facebook.com` will make the difference, but this requires slow testing.

I'm currently waiting for more data to be collected using the filter, so I don't know the answer yet. I am creating this question now in case others have already figured this out and to create a breadcrumb for myself later. Hopefully I can come back and answer my own question with a best-practice with the shortest possible path to getting IA traffic to be both identifiable in GA and reliably stored in **Channels > Social > Facebook**

Comment: Hi @jerclarke. A few minutes ago I stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/42587025/1238150. I have a similar task in front of me. How did your story end? Were you able to resolve it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Short version: I was able to get the IA traffic into the Social channel group, but not into Facebook, no matter what I tried (the "Social Network" is always listed as "(not set)", so our analyst always has to mentally/manually merge the not-set/ia traffic in with Facebook). 

Your idea of using medium=referral seems like the kind of thing that might fix this, but I wonder if it did. Screenshots of what you get in GA would be welcome.

Comment: I'll try to find time to update this with my latest findings

Comment: Yes, of course, you can find screenshots here: https://gist.github.com/natterstefan/7e00e1dff512c703e6275a609a4b896c.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it and summarized the "How to" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54112349/1238150. Hope this helps you and probably others as well.